# ionic 3 Change grid dynamically

Tags: ionic3, angular5

In following code Sometimes `{{Data3}}` or `{{Data2}}` will not have any value

**Scenario 1 : `{{Data3}}`  will not have any value**

```
 <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-4>{{Data1}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4>{{Data2}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4 >{{Data3}}</ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

Now I need change first two col into two grid 
Something like:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>{{Data1}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>{{Data2}}</ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

**Scenario 2 : `{{Data3}}` and `{{Data2}}` will not have any value**

```
 <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-4>{{Data1}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4>{{Data2}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col col-4 >{{Data3}}</ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

Now I need change first two col into one grid 
Something like:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12>{{Data1}}</ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

How can I change attribute of `<ion-col>` dynamically on particular conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution [attr.col-4]="condition1" [attr.col-6]="condition2" Like

```
<ion-col *ngIf="Data1" [attr.col-4]="condition1" [attr.col-6]="condition2">{{Data1}}</ion-col>
<ion-col  *ngIf="Data2" [attr.col-4]="condition1" [attr.col-6]="condition2">{{Data2}}</ion-col>
<ion-col  *ngIf="Data3" [attr.col-4]="condition1" [attr.col-6]="condition2">{{Data3}}</ion-col>
```

Comment: what is condition1 and condition2, if you dont mind can you please give one full example. Im also looking same.. I have 3 columns, first im planning to display two columns(col-4 and col-8), onclick of some show button, im planning to display 3 columns(col-4, col-4 and col-4).. please help me

Comment: The accepted solution doesn't work, the conditional set's the attribute value to true or false, but doesn't remove the attribute, so the browser renderer still processes col-4 and col-6

Comment: if you want to hide the attribute, use null instead false

Answer (score 4):

i hope this snippet code help you for make dynamic col

```
<ion-col *ngFor="let button of data.buttons.list;"
    [attr.col-1]="data.buttons.col == 1 ? '' : null"
    [attr.col-2]="data.buttons.col == 2 ? '' : null"
    [attr.col-3]="data.buttons.col == 3 ? '' : null"
    [attr.col-4]="data.buttons.col == 4 ? '' : null"
    [attr.col-6]="data.buttons.col == 6 ? '' : null"
    [attr.col-12]="data.buttons.col == 12 ? '' : null"
>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the content you want columns to be of equal width which is the grid's [default behavior](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#equal-width).

> By default, columns will take up equal width inside of a row for all devices and screen sizes.

What you really need to do is not have a column if data is not present.

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngIf="Data1">{{Data1}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col  *ngIf="Data2">{{Data2}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col  *ngIf="Data3">{{Data3}}</ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

Comment: when there are data of two columns(Data1 and Data2) then divide it into two columns by attribute col-6.when there are data of one column(Data1 ) then divide it into one column by attribute col-12

Comment: My challange is how to toggle col-12 or col-6 dynamically on certain conditions

Comment: you dont have to set col attribute.. In this case it will autmatically set as you require